# Hibernate not setting auto generated id after the save

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm using the hibernate template save method for inserting the rows.
After the insert, hibernate is not setting the auto-generated ID column in the object.

In the below  code userId is setting as 0

```
TDUserMaster userMaster = new TDUserMaster();
userMaster.setUserName(userName);
Serializable id = getHibernateTemplate().save(userMaster);
userId = userMaster.getUserId();
```

POJO class :

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "USERID")
private Integer userId;

@Column(name = "USERNAME")
private String userName;
```

Comment: What database are you using ?

Comment: MS-SQL, But It should work for all the DB

Answer (score 1):

you can use GenerationType.IDENTITY instead of  GenerationType.AUTO.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the below line and check. it will work as its work in my case.

@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long reportInfoId; //primary key

Answer (score 0):

**hi pramod**
can you try like

```
getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().openSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
session.save(userMaster);
userId = userMaster.getUserId();
```